# How to catch returned value from mutation in another mutation Vuex

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, mutation

I am trying to access to a getter from an action but it is giving an error that: `getters.isCardLiked is not a function`

store/index.js

```js
export const getters = {

  isCardLiked(state, id) {
    const found = state.likedCards.find(likedCard => likedCard.id === id)
    console.log('found', found); // object
    return found
  },
  
 },
 
export const actions = {

  likedCardsHandler({ dispatch, commit, getters }, id) {
    console.log('here', getters.isCardLiked(id));
  },
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`likedCardsHandler` is an action or a mutation?
If it's an action, you can find it in the [action context](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions) and use it from there.

With something [like this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#actions)

```js
actions: {
  likedCardsHandler ({ getters }) {
    console.log('here', getters.isCardLiked)
  }
}
```

Otherwise, I guess you could try `const card = isCardLiked`.

`this` is not defined in the store itself since it's a `.js` file.

Comment: likedCardsHandler is a mutation

Comment: @RustamRavshanovich from what you're doing inside of `isCardLiked`, it should be more of a getter. And `likedCardsHandler` should be an action. A `mutation` is only responsible for the mutation of a single state.

Comment: I did it exactly as you said `isCardLiked` is a getter now and I am calling it from an action `likedCardsHandler` and I am trying to access to a getter like `const card = getters.isCardLiked(id)` but it is giving me an error  `getters.isCardLiked is not a function`

Comment: @RustamRavshanovich destructure it as shown here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions I've edited my answer.

Comment: still getting an error, `console.log('here', getters.isCardLiked(id))` I am trying to give payload to a getter. I cant understand why it is happening I did exactly same thing in my another action and it is working, but in this getting error

Answer (score 1):

You could use computed method with filter for returning found object like this. So I am guessing there is a like button such as this.
Store page

```
import createStore from 'vuex';
const store=createStore({

state:{
cards:{
  A:{
   id:1.
   likes:0
 }, 
 B:{
 id:2,
 likes:0
 }
}
}
actions:{
   changeCards({commit}, payload){
   commit('changeCard',payload)
 }
}
mutations:{
  changeCard(state,payload){
  if(state.cards.id==payload)
  state.cards.likes++;
}
}

})
export default store;
```

Now in the App.js

```
  <ul>
  <li v-for="card in cards">
  <button @click="likeButtonClicked(card.id)">Like</button>
  </li>
  </ul>
   <li v-for="likedCard in likedCards">{{likedCard}}
     </li>
 <ul>
<li></li>
</ul>

 methods:{
  likeButtonClicked(id){
   this.$store.dispatch('changeCards',id);
 }
}



computed:{
  cards(){

  return this.$store.state.cards;
}
likedCards(){
  return cards.filter(card=>card.id.includes(this.$store.state.cards.likes>0))
}
```

I hope you are getting the point of all this. I hope this helps

Comment: No, I am just pushing that card/object to a Favourites and to a localStorage to show to a user his liked cards

Answer (score 1):

```js
export const getters = {

  isCardLiked: (state) => (id) => {
    const found = state.likedCards.find(likedCard => likedCard.id === id)
    console.log('found', found); // object
    return found
  },
 }
 
 export const actions = {
 likedCardsHandler({ dispatch, commit, getters }, id) {
    console.log('here', getters.isCardLiked(id));
   }
  },
 }
```

Especially thank to @kissu